# How to show other Attribute Value on Filter in product page

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Sir We Have Face A Problem When We Filter Product To Specify Attributes Other Value are Not Show

Example 
We Have Color Attr

RED
GREEN
BLUE
ORANGE
 When we Filter with **Geeen** RED,BLUE,ORANGE are not Show
I Want to Show RED,BLUE,ORANGE That We filter other Product With This Color

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with default Magento. When you filter by 1 attribute the collection of products shown wil be filtered. Only the attributes and values of the remaining products will be shown as filters then.

I know of a module by amasty which can dowhat you want (filter by multiple attribute values without loosing the other attribute values). The configuration of this Amasty module should not be too much work depending on the quality of the template you are using.

Its this module:
https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html

Comment: Another extension you may want to vet is: https://www.gomage.com/gomage-advanced-navigation.html

This can be used to filter by multiple colors.

Comment: a have no experience with the goMage module, good addition though

Comment: The gomage extension is ok, but you have to be careful because you can have too many attributes/products and kill performance. To be fair, default magento swatches have the same issue, which can be shown on a demo site by making an ALL products category and showing all products, the swatches take FOREVER to render according to z-ray.